# pgfplots-siunitx: Removing decimal zeros of \pgfmathsetmacro when printed by \SI

Tags: pgfplots, siunitx, pgfmath

Here, I used `\sisetup{round-mode=off,add-decimal-zero=false,round-precision=0}` to suppress the decimal zeros. However, I couldn't get `100` instead of `100.0` as I need.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\sisetup{round-mode=off,add-decimal-zero=false,round-precision=0}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\t}{2*50}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(0,1)} node[pin=150:{%
        $\SI{\t}{\us}$%
    }]{} ;
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\t}{2*50}`

Comment: @egreg Would be an answer from the other 'aspect' to mine: will you post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine `\t` here you get

```
> \t=macro:
->100.0.
```

so `siunitx` is doing exactly what you'd expect with no rounding, *etc.*, active: preserving the value as given. You'll need to remove the trailing zero either at the `pgf` end or perhaps by rounding to no places:

```
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=0}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I got lost in understanding the meaning of these options in other answers.